# Plot "stacked" density distributions of variables, categorized by 0 or 1, in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, distribution

I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 6)), columns = ['Var_1', 'Var_2', 'Var_3', 'Var_4', 'Var_5', 'Var_6']) 
df['Status'] = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(100, 1))
df

Out[1]: 
    Var_1  Var_2  Var_3  Var_4  Var_5  Var_6  Status
0      32     65     48     83     60     21       1
1      44     49     65     84     52     34       1
2       9      2      3     14     82     80       1
3      66     90     97     60     28     12       0
4      28     95     64     53     39     30       1
..    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...     ...
95     22      4     43      9     79     46       1
96     10     26     91     59     99     93       0
97     10     31     33     15     99     25       1
98     41     48     80     65     58     18       1
99     39     42     22     56     91     40       1

[100 rows x 7 columns]
```

How can I create a "stacked" density distribution plot of each variable, categorized by `Status` (0 or 1). I would like the plot to look like this:

[image]

This plot was was created in R. The plot in Python does not have to look exactly the same. What code could I use to accomplish this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adaption of seaborn's [ridgeplot example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html) for the given structure. Here `multiple='stack'` is selected in `sns.kdeplot` (the default is `multiple='layer'` plotting them both starting from `y=0`). Note that `common_norm` defaults to `True`, which scales down both curves in proportion to the number of samples.

As seaborn works with data in ["long form"](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data), `pd.melt()` transforms the given dataframe. The long form looks like:

```py
      Status variable      value
0          0    Var 1  -0.961877
1          1    Var 1   6.454942
2          0    Var 1   6.020015
3          0    Var 1   7.094057
4          0    Var 1  10.289022
      ...      ...        ...
2995       0    Var 6  -5.718156
2996       0    Var 6  -5.142314
2997       0    Var 6  -5.155104
2998       1    Var 6   3.339401
2999       1    Var 6   7.912669
```

Here is a full code example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

# Create the data
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
data = rs.randn(30, 100).cumsum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 6)
column_names = [f'Var {i}' for i in range(1, 7)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)
df['Status'] = rs.randint(0, 2, len(df))
for col in column_names:
    df.loc[df['Status'] == 1, col] += 5
df_long = df.melt(id_vars='Status', value_vars=column_names)

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df_long, row="variable", aspect=6, height=1.8)

# Draw the densities
g.map_dataframe(sns.kdeplot, "value",
                bw_adjust=.5, clip_on=False, fill=True, alpha=1, linewidth=1.5,
                hue="Status", hue_order=[0, 1], palette=['tomato', 'turquoise'], multiple='stack')
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False, color='black')

# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, x.iloc[0], fontweight="bold", color='black',
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)

g.map(label, "variable")

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[], xlabel="")
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn ridge plot with stacked kdeplots]